# OWIN middleware notifications not being called from MSAL for Azure B2C directory

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, owin-middleware

Currently I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out...

I have an Azure B2C Angular SPA app that uses MSAL in the front-end. In the back-end it's ASP.NET MVC with full .NET Framework.

I had an application working beautifully with ADAL in the front-end (SPA app) and `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` in the back-end (ASP.NET MVC).

Now I'm working with **Azure B2C** and making use of **MSAL**.

I can login with MSAL in the front-end but the middleware configured in the backend ASP.NET MVC won't fire.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    // Generate the metadata address using the tenant and policy information
    MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),

    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,

   // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
    ClientId = ClientId,
    RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,

    // Specify the callbacks for each type of notifications
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    },

    // Specify the claim type that specifies the Name property.
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name"
    },

    // Specify the scope by appending all of the scopes requested into one string (separated by a blank space)
    Scope = $"openid profile offline_access user_impersonation"
}
);
```

In the front-end I call:

```
msalService.loginPopup();

$rootScope.$on("msal:loginSuccess", function () {
    console.log("loginSuccess");

    var token = msalService.userInfo.idToken;
});
```

I get the `id token` and the login happens successfully...

I put breakpoints in all notification handlers inside the OWIN middleware:

- OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
- OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
- OnAuthenticationFailed

but the debugger never stops there, that is, the middleware code is not being called.

Why is the notification handlers not being fired? Am I missing something or using the wrong middleware?

Ultimately what I want to achieve is to be able to extract the id_token inside the middleware and do some back-end additional logic\processing. Add custom claims, etc. I was able to do this using `ADAL` and the `UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` middleware as I mentioned before. Right after the user logged in I had the opportunity to hook into the middleware's notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... turns out that this app I'm working on was messing up with cookies in the front-end and that was causing some conflict with the token set by MSAL. As soon as I removed cookie related code, the OWIN notification handler was hit when making the `XHR` request.

I got to that conclusion when I checked *Chrome Developer Tools* and saw there was an invalid **authorization** header being sent. It had `[Object object]` as value.

[image]

However I had to change the OWIN middleware. It's now `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication`:

```
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(tvps, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider(string.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy))),

    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = async context =>
        {
            try
            {
                 .
                 .
                 .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the `OnValidateIdentity` is hit every time a request reaches the back-end server and I have the opportunity to check claims or add new ones.